# Solve stock market puzzle in java for max profit

Tags: java, algorithm

Need max profit.

What can I modify to get the max profit if I can only buy once and sell once?
Means if I buy at 5 and sell at 150 then its max profit.

Currently what I have done is buy when price is less than next day, and sell if price is more than next day.

As obviously we have to keep in mind we can sell only after we buy, means sell index can not be before buy index.

What I have done so far is:

```
package com;

public class Stock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] prices = {20,10,70,80,5,150,67};
        int length = prices.length-2;
        int buy=0;
        int sell=0;
        int buyIndex=-1;
        int sellIndex=-1;

        int i=0;
        for (i =0 ; i<=length ;i++ ){

            // buy logic start
            if(prices[i]<prices[i+1]){
                if(i>buyIndex){
                    buy= prices[i];
                    buyIndex=i; 
                    System.out.println("buy"+buy);
                    System.out.println("buyIndex"+buyIndex);
                }               
            } // buy logic finish


         // sell logic start
            if(buy!=0 && i>buyIndex ){
                System.out.println("inside sell logic");
                if(prices[i]>prices[i+1]){
                    sell = prices[i];
                    sellIndex = i;
                    System.out.println("sell"+sell);
                    System.out.println("sellIndex"+sellIndex);

                }
            } // sell logic end
        } // for loop end

    } // main end

}
```

output is

```
buy10
buyIndex1
buy70
buyIndex2
inside sell logic
sell80
sellIndex3
buy5
buyIndex4
inside sell logic
sell150
sellIndex5
```

Comment: Smells like a homework. Btw, I don't see this strictly as an issue related with programming.

Comment: @BranislavLazic its not homework. i am just trying some puzzles. and i know very well that before asking here we must do try ourself , so i tried to do it. and posted what i have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can define 2 auxillary arrays: min and max, where:

```
min[0] = array[0]
min[i] = min(min[i-1], array[i]    0 < i < n
```

Intuitively, min[i] is the smallest number seen, that came before (or at) index `i`.

Similary, `max`:

```
max[0] = array[n-1]
max[i] = max(max[i+1], array[i])   0 <= i < n-1
```

Intuitively, max[i] is the biggest number after or at `i`.

Now, once you have these arrays, `max[i] - min[i]` is the maximal profit achieved by a stock that can be bought at most at day `i`, and sold at least at date `i`. If you traverse over all `i`s, which is basically the definition of valid transaction.

If you go over all `0 <= i < n`, you will find the optimal solution.

(Note, optimization can eliminate the need for extra space by remembering the local min, but I'd start with the extra space solution, which in my opinion has clearer logic)

---

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i will try to do what you suggested.